Show a small spinner at the right edge of a table cell - best CSS?
I have a Custom Datatype with standardCellLayout: false set - HTML below - that I'm using in lightning-datatable for some data that arrives a few seconds after the table is rendered.
My problem is how to make the spinner appear at the right side of the table cell instead of in the center. Anyone know the CSS to achieve that? My guesses have not worked...
<template>

    <!-- Would like this right aligned too but couldn't figure out how to do that -->
    <lightning-spinner
        lwc:if={showSpinner}
        alternative-text="Loading"
        variant="brand"
        size="x-small"
    ></lightning-spinner>

    <!-- Numeric value -->
    <div lwc:elseif={showValue} class="slds-float_right">
        {prefix}<lightning-formatted-number
            format-style={formatStyle}
            value={displayValue}
            currency-code={currencyCode}
            minimum-fraction-digits={minimumFractionDigits}
            maximum-fraction-digits={maximumFractionDigits}
        ></lightning-formatted-number>{suffix}
    </div>

    <!-- Otherwise nothing -->

</template>


you can add slds-is-relative to the cell, so the spinner is only showing in the cell, I'll double check now regarding spinner alignment inside container

does the answer work for you, Keith?

Hi @ytiq, Yes I think it would as the context is a Digital Experience. But what I've ended up using is the "strength" type of lightning-dynamic-icon as this looks better in a table and can be right aligned. But annoyingly you have to animate that yourself by updating the option string via setInterval JavaScript.

setInterval seems not optimal if you want to do it for each cell, I'm not sure how it'll scale to big tables. If you want to use dynamic-icon maybe 'eq' would work for you since it's already animated?

just out curiocity what's the use case to have individual spinners on cells?

Hi @ytiq I want most of a table to render immediately and then fill in some slow to calculate values (e.g. IRR: iterative algorithm and sometimes requires async calculation because of governor limits) once they are available.

Unfortunately, you can't change align spinner itself using slds tokens or classes and you can change style for spinner because of shadow DOM.
So you have 2 options

use styling from LDS site and customize it
override styles with a static resource.

I think the first option is simpler, so the final version would look like that.
<template>

    <!-- Would like this right aligned too but couldn't figure out how to do that -->
    <div 
        lwc:if={showSpinner}
        class="slds-spinner_container"
    >
        <div role="status" class="slds-spinner slds-spinner_brand slds-spinner_x-small">
            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
            <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
            <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Numeric value -->
    <div lwc:elseif={showValue} class="slds-float_right">
        {prefix}<lightning-formatted-number
            format-style={formatStyle}
            value={displayValue}
            currency-code={currencyCode}
            minimum-fraction-digits={minimumFractionDigits}
            maximum-fraction-digits={maximumFractionDigits}
        ></lightning-formatted-number>{suffix}
    </div>

    <!-- Otherwise nothing -->

</template>

:host {
    position: relative;
}
.myContainer .slds-spinner {
    left: initial;
    right: 0;
}

P.S. I'd recommend avoiding slds-float_right because floats are evil
